Instance scheduler in aws
I've used the default template for aws instance scheduler . the stack is creating and dynamo db is also creating .When i changed the time zone and office hours the server is not starting and stopping. What might be the problem ? I've implemented the correct steps.
I tried all but instance is not starting and stopping within the scheduled offic ehours. Suggest a way to resolve the problem.

Welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal reproducible example to try to reproduce the error and debug it.

if you time zone of your office and time zone of instance scheduler is different you will likely face issue of instance starting and stopping in wrong hours.
also check if the instance is tagged properly with required key value pair, where value being the schedule defined in dynamo db.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
